# How does the TeX Live Manager pick mirrors if none is manually specified?

Tags: texlive, ctan

I assumed that the TeX Live Manager would pick random mirrors if you didn't specify one (or random within the same continent or such). [When I asked a question about this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/286531/automatically-find-fastest-ctan-mirror) @cfr thought it would automatically pick the fastest mirror. What does the TeX Live Manager for Windows actually do?

Comment: See https://www.ctan.org/mirrors where the structure is explained: the address `http://mirror.ctan.org` points to a multiplexor that chooses one of the official mirrors, according to some criterion depending on the network topology. Mirrors are monitored, so slow or inactive ones can be excluded, see https://www.ctan.org/mirrors/mirmon

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What `tlmgr` actually does is explained in egreg's answer partially:

- it connects to mirror.ctan.org and asks for a mirror
- it extracts the actual mirror address from the html response
- it uses this (the same) address for all operations of this run

The additional two steps are done to ensure that in one run of `tlmgr` all connections are to the same server, and not to different servers in case there is a time squeeze of syncronization.

On the `mirror.ctan.org` an IP-country based approach is used to determine a supposedly close mirror.

In addition we do have a list of mirrors that can be selected during installation, which is updated every week.

Comment: Country based? THAT explains a lot. There are only a few Canadian mirrors, and at least one is on the far side of the continent from me.

Comment: @Canagreek don't take my word for granted what the mirroring service is actually doing, I'm not operating it.

Comment: Ah, so we'd need to ask the TeX Live people for that.

Comment: no, the mlctan mirroring service is not managed by TeX Live. I know the TeX Live part, but the CTAN part is separate.